# XSLT - split string on every nth character

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Hi guys

I want to create an xslt 2.0 stylesheet to do the following:

Split the xml element value below:

```
<sample>Please Move the asset as below

Asset Name: My Monitor 40 inch_123456789123
Asset Serial Number: 123456789123

Current Details:
Costcenter: 1234-123456 MY COST CENTRE
Location: 12 - 1234 - 1234 - MY COST ADDRESS,12 MY STR.,10TH FLOOR,,CITY,Country Name

Destination Details: 
Cost Center: 1234-12345 : 5678-91234 Some Place</sample>
```

on every 70th character, and then assign the first 9 results each to a fixed, configured new element name, and discard any left over matches. Example:

```
<humpty>first 70chars</humpty>
<dumpty>second70chars</dumpty>
<sat>third70chars</sat>
etc...
```

I thought about using tokenize but got stuck, because it requires a string pattern to match on. I thought about using substring, but I'm unsure about the format.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: You can use `analyze-string`. I am however not sure where you want to get the new element names like `humpty` from

Comment: Thanks Martin. The new element names will be pre-configured in the stylesheet and always stay the same. For the sake of the example I used `humpty` and the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the element names and simply want to extract substrings of 70 characters then http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring should do:

```
<xsl:template match="sample">
  <humpty><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 70)"/></humpty>
  <dumpty><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 71, 70)"/></dumpty>
  <sat><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 141, 70)"/></sat>
  ...
</xsl:template>
```